# The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columns specified

Tags: windows, windows-10, ms-dos

Whenever I try and open `cmd` it flashes and just closes it itself after showing the below error for a split second.

```
The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columns specified.
```

Tried the below solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664039/where-in-windows-registry-the-console-width-is-stored), the `CursorSize` value is already 19 (Hex) but I don’t which key does the other value pertains to.

Comment: In case it helps any francophones in future, the French equivalent of this error is "Impossible de configurer l'écran au nombre de lignes et de colonnes spécifié"

Answer (score 1):

Ran Malwarebytes to check if it picks up something this time.

To configure the command prompt
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491037.aspx

You could download the Autoruns tool to disable some unused plugins.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

You’d better create a new user account and restart explorer.exe process to check.